# Why does Quinn look like he lost 10-20 lbs between season 4 and 5?

Tags: character, dexter

In Season 4, Quinn is thin, but looks pretty healthy:

[image: Quinn in Season 4]

In Season 5, Quinn starts to look a bit more like Skeletor - his cheeks are sunken, and in general he looks like he lost about 20-30 lbs that he didn't need to.

[image]

Is there any in or out of show explanation for the change in appearance?

Comment: Do you have screenshot from season 5?

Comment: @AnkitSharma edited to include one from (I assume) the actual show. The lighting really shows off his extreme weight loss.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Desmond Harrington explains](http://www.dexterdaily.com/2012/12/desmond-harrington-comes-clean-about.html):

> Dexter co-star Desmond Harrington -finally- comes clean about his
>   weigh loss: "I didn't have any plastic surgery, I'm not sick **it's
>   called running and eating better!** You understand? I'm in my 30s now.
>   All these ridiculous stuff that I read "He's sick, he's on drugs", get
>   a life! **I just changed how I ate and begin to run!**"
>
> [Listen to the whole -hilarious- Dexter Wrap-Up Podcast](http://www.dexterdaily.com/2012/12/dexter-wrap-up-listen-to-scott-reynolds.html).